Attain a particular configuration from a given initial configuration in a 3x2/2x3 board
The preface is the same as the well known 15 Sliding Puzzle/ 8 Sliding Puzzle. But this one is a miniaturized form of it with a 2x3 board. Given a initial configuration of the board and a final configuration of the board, can we tell:
(a) If the final config is "attainable" from initial config.
(b) Optimal steps to reach the final config (if attainable)
I know that one has something to do with no of of inversion pairs for a nxn game board. However what does one have to do for a mxn matrix? I have also seen some concept like "parity of permutation" being mentioned in a few places, but I don't understand how a transformation is done from the game board to that permutation, and how to use that to do when given an initial and final config and not just an initial config.

Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! In short, yes. This is a finite game.

See this question for some hints towards a (non-optimal) solving strategy, and here or here for how to determine whether it is solvable or not.

@JaapScherphuis I have read the exact questions you have mentioned before, however couldn't understand how they approached it. I wanted someone to help explain the solvable part with an example if possible.

The simplest explanation is Deusovi's one here. Where are you having trouble?
